# How to partition a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'd like to write a function template, `apply`, which receives some function `f`, an integer `i`, and a parameter pack. `apply` needs to unpack the parameters and apply `f` to them, except for the `i`th parameter, `pi`. For `pi`, it needs to call some other function `g` before passing it as a parameter to `f`.

It seems that I need a way to partition the parameter pack into a left side, the `i`th parameter, and the right side.  Is this possible?  In code:

```
template<int i, typename Function, typename... Parms>
  void apply(Function f, Parms... parms)
{
  auto lhs = // what goes here?
  auto pi =  // what goes here?
  auto rhs = // what goes here?

  f(lhs..., g(pi), rhs...);
}
```

Comment: pi is available as M_PI in math.h.  Not sure about the rest, can you post code with less ellipsis?

Comment: @HansPassant I think OP means `ith-parameter` by `pi`

Comment: @HansPassant C++ now went the entire way: you don't need to write all the code anymore! The ellipsis are actually code and are being executed!

Comment: @HansPassant: The "ellipses" are part of the code. It's C++11 variadic template syntax.

Comment: with respect to the original question: I wouldn't partition the code. Instead, I would create a helper which is takes the position of the parameter and `i`. If the position is not `i` return the argument, if it is `i` return the result of `g(a)`. You want the Full Monty?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Yup C++11 is so advanced it knows what the programmer wants the program to do. From now on all new C++ code will look like this: `int main(int argc, char **argv) {...}`

Comment: It's certainly possible with a dedicated template specialization for each `i`... but you'd prefer a more sophisticated solution?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I want `i` to be 1000. While you type out the specializations I do a proper solution ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here we go! It **really** ugly but I couldn't come up with a nicer version in a hurry ;) Most of the stuff is bog standard template specialization. The biggest issue is creating a list of integers of the proper size. I seem to recall that I came up with a nice version but somehow I can't recall what I did. Enjoy!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// printing the values
void print_args() {}
template <typename F> void print_args(F f) { std::cout << f; }
template <typename F, typename... T>
void print_args(F f, T... args)
{
    std::cout << f << ", ";
    print_args(args...);
}

// the function object to be called:
struct Functor
{
    template <typename... T>
    void operator()(T... args)
    {
        std::cout << "f(";
        print_args(args...);
        std::cout << ")\n";
    }
};

// conditionally apply g():
template <typename T> T g(T value) { return 1000 + value; }
template <int i, int j, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<i != j, T>::type forward(T t) { return t; }
template <int i, int j, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<i == j, T>::type forward(T t) { return g(t); }

// create a series of integers:
template <int... Values> struct values {};

template <int Add, typename> struct combine_values;
template <int Add, int... Values>
struct combine_values<Add, values<Values...>>
{
    typedef values<Values..., Add> type;
};

template <int Size> struct make_values;
template <> struct make_values<0> { typedef values<> type; };
template <int Size>
struct make_values
{
    typedef typename combine_values<Size, typename make_values<Size -1>::type>::type type;
};

// applying f(t...) except for ti where g(ti) is called
template <int i, int... Values, typename Function, typename... T>
void apply_aux(values<Values...>, Function f, T... t)
{
    f(forward<i, Values>(t)...);
}

template <int i, typename Function, typename... T>
void apply(Function f, T... t)
{
    apply_aux<i>(typename make_values<sizeof...(T)>::type(), f, t...);
}

int main()
{
    apply<3>(Functor(), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    apply<4>(Functor(), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    apply<5>(Functor(), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
}
```

Comment: Ended up using this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Iactually did code something similar a little while ago. So try the following code:

```
template<unsigned N, unsigned M>
struct call_up_impl{
    template<class Func, class Mutator, class Tuple, class... Args>
    static void do_call(const Func& func, const Mutator& mutator, const Tuple& args, Args&&... unpacked_args) {
        call_up_impl<N-1, M>::do_call(func, mutator, args, std::get<N-1>(args), std::forward<Args>(unpacked_args)...);
    }
};

template<unsigned M>
struct call_up_impl<0, M> {
    template<class Func, class Mutator, class Tuple, class... Args>
    static void do_call(const Func& func, const Mutator&, const Tuple&, Args&&... unpacked_args) {
        func(std::forward<Args>(unpacked_args)...);
    }
};
template<unsigned M>
struct call_up_impl<M, M> {
    template<class Func, class Mutator, class Tuple, class... Args>
    static void do_call(const Func& func, const Mutator& mutator, const Tuple& args, Args&&... unpacked_args) {
        call_up_impl<M-1, M>::do_call(func, mutator, args, mutator(std::get<M-1>(args)), std::forward<Args>(unpacked_args)...);
    }
};
template<int i, typename Function, typename... Parms>
void apply(Function f, Parms... parms) {
      std::tuple<Parms...> t(parms...);
      call_up_impl<std::tuple_size<decltype(t)>::value, i + 1>::do_call(f, &g, t);
}
```

This is a quick adaption of my original code, so it isn't thoroughly tested and maybe not the not optimal way to do this, but it should work at least (at least according to a quick test and depending what exactly you want). It should be possible to do this without the tuple, but I haven't gotten that to compile with g++ (it doesn't seem to like the nested variadic templates needed). However changing `apply` to:

```
template<int i, typename Function, typename... Parms>
void apply(Function f, Parms&&... parms) {
      std::tuple<Parms&&...> t(std::forward<Parms>(parms)...);
      call_up_impl<std::tuple_size<decltype(t)>::value, i + 1>::do_call(f, &g, t);
}
```

will probably avoid most of the overhead introduced by the tuple. It would be even better to make correct forwarding of the results of the `std::get` calls, but I'm too tired to work that out write now.

Comment: I think this looks more complicated and also depends on `std::tuple` to do all the work! Sure, I'm also using a standard class (`std::enable_if`) but compared to `std::tuple` is the implementation of `std::enable_if` trivial. Quite a bit of my code is also actually applying the operation and printing the results.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I disagree with the the looking more complicated part. And whats the problem with relying on `std::tuple`, if we are bound to C++11 only due to using variadic templates anyways? (besides with variadic templates implementing the necessary tuple operations is pretty easy too). So what is the problem?

Comment: Both solutions are interesting. Thanks for providing them. Still, I'm disappointed that there's no more direct solution in c++11.